# How to load a new page with AngularJS when a user start typing in an input box

Tags: angularjs

My route /search shows a Template and related Controller that are showing a list of entries from my database (properly binding data using from the Controller to the Template using the $scope variable). So if I go to /search it just works and shows data.

Now I have added a search box at the top of my page. When the user starts typing, wherever he is on the website, I would like to show results instantly (showing Template with results).

What is the Angular way to do that?

---

**Here is my how I finally did it:**

My route:

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '<%= asset_path "welcome/index.html" %>' });
  $routeProvider.when('/search', { templateUrl: '<%= asset_path "search/index.html" %>', controller: 'SearchController' });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

The global layout:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" data-ng-controller="SearchController">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" data-ng-model="query" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>

<div data-ng-view></div>
```

The Controller:

```
angular.module('tastyPie.controllers')

.controller('SearchController', function($scope, Search) {

  // Bind to the view
  $scope.searchResults = [];
  $scope.query = '';

  // if the user is not on the search page and start typing, move him to the search page and perform a search
  $scope.$watch('query', function(new_data, old_data) {
    if (new_data == old_data) return;

    if ($location.path().indexOf('/search') < 0)
      $location.path('search');

    $scope.search();
  });

  $scope.search = function() {
    var s = new Search();
    s.query = $('#query').val();
    s.execute();
  };

  // callback from the search services which returns the results
  $scope.$on('searchResults', function(object, results){
    $scope.searchResults = results;
  });

});
```

And the template search/index.html :

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-init="search()">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="result in searchResults">
    <strong>{{result.title_texts}}</strong>
    <br />
    {{result}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should create a directive for that in AngularJS

Comment: The angular way is to execute an HTTP request each time the entered value changes, and display the result using an ng-repeat directive, for example. Read the doc for input[type=text], ngRepeat, and $http.

Comment: I did a proper binding of my data using the $scope variable between my controller and template (and using $http, ng-repeat). I just can't figure out how to show all of this when a user start typing a query?

Comment: So, where is your code?

Comment: just added the code! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I understand better what you want to do. Here's how I would try doing it, with my limited angular experience:

- Define a SearchService
- Inject this service into the main controller, which handles the search text field
- Have this main controller set the search text value in the search service each time it changes, and set the location to /search if it's not already the case
- Have a search controller associated with a div displaying the search results
- In this search controller, inject the SearchService
- In this search controller, use `$scope.watch()` to be notified each time the search text value stored in the SearchService is modified
- each time the search text value is modified, execute an HTTP request to get the search results, store the results in the scope, and let the view iterate through the results.

Comment: yes sorry I'm using slim template. When I add the search() call I get the following error: "Error: No controller: ngModel". Should I add anything else?

Comment: Start by editing your question and posting the correct, updated HTML code.

Comment: @vincentp: now that the HTML code is posted, re-readthe last part of my answer. Forget about ng-view. Post the ng-repeat in the same HTML page as the search input, inside the form, and without ng-init attribute: the ng-repeat gets its results from the scope of the controller, so it must be inside the element with the ng-controller attribute.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have it already working when I go to /search, my question was how do I load the template content when I'm on the home page (/) for example and I start typing into the input box. I have added my route and more code so I hope it will make more sense

Comment: thanks a lot, I finally got it to work, I have updated my question with the final code!

Comment: One more suggestion to make this goes smoother and reduce request to your server is you should define a timeout when user stop typing with `keyup` event.